# hide google doc bar to play presentation

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have the code below which i am using from google docs to display a presentation, i would like to know is there any method of me hide the bar at the bottom so that it does not show up.

```
<div style="width: 960; height: 540; 
    background-color:White;">
<div style="z-index: -2;"><iframe src="https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1FYhFR3a49gvmyqozJbtNe3eP7FogKJRwGE9bN7tihSs/embed?start=true&amp;loop=false&amp;delayms=3000" frameborder="0" width="960" height="569"></iframe></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `z-index` only works with `position:` css rule!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set parent div height less the `iframe` height and use `overflow: hidden;` in parent div.

Try this code

```
<div style="width: 960px; height: 540px;background-color:White; overflow: hidden;">
      <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1FYhFR3a49gvmyqozJbtNe3eP7FogKJRwGE9bN7tihSs/embed?start=true&amp;loop=false&amp;delayms=3000" frameborder="0" width="960" height="569"></iframe>
</div>
```

[<kbd>**DEMO**</kbd>](http://jsbin.com/rilesesi/1/edit?output)

Answer (score 1):

try adding rm=minimal

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1FYhFR3a49gvmyqozJbtNe3eP7FogKJRwGE9bN7tihSs/embed?start=true&loop=false&delayms=3000&rm=minimal" frameborder="0" width="960" height="569"></iframe>
```